# an issue when trying to enable virtualization

Tags: android, android-studio, intel, virtualization, bios

I have a problem with virtualization in my Samsung NP270E5E. when I try to open the virtual device from Android Studio , an error tells me that the intel HAXM is not installed .

http://www.upimg.fr/ih/bvd8.png

I tried to install the intel HAXM , but an other error tells me that the Intel Virtualization is not turned on

http://www.upimg.fr/ih/yvo0.png

so when I tried to turn it on from the bios startup (my bios is : Phoenix SecureCore Tiano)  I did not find the Enable/Disable option (I think some options are hidden from the bios menu )

is there an other  way to run the avd without this problem and how I can enable the virtualization from my Phoenix bios ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the **x86** or **x86_64** ABI version of your API Level?

If so try to use the **armeabi-v7a** version, so the HAXM error will not appear..